# Limitar conexiones por dispositivos

Tags: php7

Necesito ayuda simplemente por saber si existe algún método para que al conectar a una webapp solo se pueda hacer con un máximo de dos dispositivos. Estoy en un proyecto de clases para alumnos hecho en php 7 pero no quiero que se pasen entre los alumnos las claves de acceso. Quisiera saber si puedo registrar el dispositivo de alguna manera en la bbdd para que si otra persona (distinta al titular de las claves) intenta acceder a la bbdd con un dispositivo no guardado, que rechace la conexión.

Comment: No entendi bien la pregunta, pero podrias crear una tabla de sesiones en tu BD donde cada vez que se inicie sesion se guarde esta "sesion" en esta tabla para que compares que el maximo sea 2

Comment: si sabes manejar algún motor de bases de datos solo tendrías que crear una tabla donde administraras cuantos dispositivos han entrado luego hacer una conexión por php y después crear un archivo de seguridad que vas a incluir en el inicio del index.php que ejecute un `die()` si ya no hay mas espacio para dispositivos

Comment: Voy a intentarlo... yo más que nada quiero que solo accedan con el móvil de ese alumno y/o su pc de casa o tablet... que no le pueda dar las claves de acceso a otra persona y se conecte también.. cada alumno tiene sus claves de acceso pero se ha dado el caso de que un alumno entra en el perfil de otro para hacerle trabajos etc... en fin, sigo averiguando algo. Gracias!